# MongoDB active diaglog file gets too big

Tags: mongodb, logging

I have a mongodb replica set. Data file sizes are quite big because there is many write operations. One mongodb node crashed because of lack of disk space because one diaglog file was 38GB.

Is there any way that diaglog files didn't get so big and instead it created multiple small(2GB or 4GB) files and then i would be able to delete unused ones?

Comment: Whats a dialog file? You mean like the programming language?

Comment: diaglog.XXX is file next to data files like this (dialog.4d65d6d) there is written diagnostic logs of operations that MongoDb server does. Write | Read + Write and so on.

Comment: Oh ok you mean that, no I think the outputting of logs to file is pretty basic atm, you might be better off using a monitoring tool like server density or something for that

Comment: Are you looking for the [logRotate](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/logRotate/) command?  I'd post it as an answer, but I am not knowledgeable enough in the area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files should only be present where there server is a config server or where the command line option has been explicitly set when starting mongod.

```
--configsvr or --diaglog
```

As this is **intended** for diagnosing specific problems you **probably** don't want this turned on all the time. In which case, remove the `--diaglog` option from startup unless you specifically put it there.

So the point is, the `--diaglog` option exists for the purpose of **very verbose** logging in order for you di *diagnose* problems. It should **not** be generally used in production environments.

If you really want it, then you are looking at log rotation and archiving methods that are a bit out of scope for the type of questions asked here.

See the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#diaglog).

Comment: As i know diaglog=1 is mandatory for replica set for oplog. Am i mistaken? I have enabled diaglog=1 for replica set to work.

Comment: @Zango this should not be **mandatory** as you say for a replica set, I gave you the conditions where it **would** exist. As suggested, remove this option from your start-up unless you require it for debugging. Otherwise live with it and rotate logs as suggested.

Comment: @Zango re-read the answer response in full to understand the meaning of using this option

Comment: @NeilLunn: `diaglog` is not specific to either config servers or replica sets. This parameter enables a general diagnostic dump of write and/or read operations, and you almost never want this enabled. I don't believe there are any easy options to rotate the diaglog short of restarting `mongod`; if `diaglog` is enabled at some non-zero logging level, a new binary diaglog.<hextimestamp> file will be created on startup.

Comment: @Stennie isn't that what I said. remove the --diaglog because it is not required? I think I said that.

Comment: @NeilLunn: you said "The files should only be present where there server is a config server or where the command line option has been explicitly set". The latter is true but this option is unrelated to the config server (and for the OP's question, unrelated to replica sets as well).

Answer (score 1):

The [`diaglog` parameter](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#diaglog) is not required for replica sets. It creates a very verbose log for troubleshooting purposes, and should definitely not be enabled by default.

You can safely remove this parameter from your `mongod` configuration and also remove the diaglog.* files in your `dbpath`.

I suspect you are confusing the `diaglog` output with the replication [`oplog` (operations log)](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/). The `oplog` is stored in the `local` database in a collection called `oplog.rs`, and is preallocated when you initialise your replica set. The [oplog size](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/#oplog-size) is 5% of free disk space by default for most 64-bit operating systems; there are some exceptions for OS X and 32-bit systems as noted in the MongoDB manual.

Comment: Note: the `diaglog` parameter has been deprecated as at the MongoDB 2.5.5 development release (ref: [SERVER-12149](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12149)), and will be removed in a future MongoDB server release.